# Why is there a fractional ideal $\mathfrak b$ such that $\mathfrak a\mathfrak b=\mathfrak o$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, dedekind-domain

For personal interest, I've been working through the exercises in Algebra(by Serge Lang) to create my own solution. Then I came across an exercise on Dedekind rings.

The exercise is as follows:

> Prove that every ideal of Dedekind ring $\mathfrak o$ is finitely generated.

with hint:

> Given an ideal $\mathfrak a$, let $\mathfrak b$ be the fractional ideal such that $\mathfrak a\mathfrak b=\mathfrak o$. Write $1=\sum a_ib_i$ with $a_i\in\mathfrak a$ and $b_i\in\mathfrak b$. Show that $\mathfrak a=(a_1,\cdots,a_n)$.

Every part except existence of $\mathfrak b$ is done. But I cannot justify that $\mathfrak b$ exists. First I tried as $\mathfrak b$ be colon ideal $(\mathfrak o:\mathfrak a)$, but I cannot justify existence of non-zero $c\in\mathfrak o$ such that $c\mathfrak b\subset\mathfrak o$.

How can I construct $\mathfrak b$? Any help is welcomed.

I want to prove this statement with definition of Lang(fractional ideals form a group), so can you avoid alternative definitions such as factorization of nonzero ideals or Krull dimension?

Comment: What is your definition of a Dedekind ring?

Comment: @AllenBell, In my book, Dedekind ring is defined as fractional ideals form a group, multiplicative group precisely.

Comment: If they form a group, every fractional ideal has a multiplicative inverse. Since clearly $\mathfrak o$ is the identy, take $\mathfrak b$ as the inverse of $\mathfrak a.$

Comment: @coffeemath $\mathfrak a$ is not fractional ideal, but just ideal of $\mathfrak o$. Is it valid yet? Even so, I am not convinced that there exists $c\in\mathfrak o$ such that $c\mathfrak b\subset\mathfrak o$.

Comment: I glossed over the distinction: so there may be ideals in a Dedekind domain which are not fractional? Then my remark is of no use... I had thought the fractional ideals were an extension of the set of ideals, so that any ideal could be regarded as a particular case of fractional ideal. [In the same way that any integer in Z is a particular kind of rational number.]

Comment: Ah god, I misunderstood!!! Yes @coffeemath your method is very useful! I recognized ideal must be fractional ideal, then its inverse $\mathfrak b$ could be answer. Thanks!

Comment: It might be interesting to take [ in a specific Dedekind ring] a specific ideal having a nice property like being a prime ideal, and explicitly construct its inverse ideal.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147629/discussion-between-coffeemath-and-mh-lee).